# Can I use Rails.cache to store short-lived session data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

We are already using cookie based sessions, and switching off them to file store sessions in not an option.  However, I need a way to store larger amounts of session data (up to 10MG or so) -- beyond the limit of cookie session and, even it weren't, round-tripping that much data on multiple requests would be slow.

I am currently attempting to solve this by using (abusing?) `Rails.cache`.  The basic setup is like this:

I post to a route, which has the following code:

```
# calculate some results...
Rails.cache.write('search_results' + session.id), search_results)
redirect_to '/results'
```

Inside `GET /results`, I read the cached data and send it to the client:

```
@results = Rails.cache.read('search_results' + session.id)
```

This works fine.  However, if I subsequently make a request to another route like `GET /results2` that *also* calls `Rails.cache.read('search_results' + session.id)`, it will return `nil`.  Even if all calls happen within a 5-10s span.

So my questions are:

1. Why does this happen?  What determines when `Rails.cache` clean itself?
2. Is there a way to make this work?
3. Is there a better approach altogether that doesn't involve using a DB or redis?

Comment: Which cache store do you use?

Comment: file store cache

Answer (score 0):

Answer to your questions:

1. The problem with file cache store is that it stores file locally. Thus, if you have multiple servers, cache can be written to one server while cache is read on another server which will return ‘nil’. The solution is to use cache store that can be shared among multiple servers.
2. Using redis-store may be a solution: https://github.com/redis-store/redis-rails

Comment: 1. it doesn’t work on my laptop, so while your multiple server point is valid it’s not the issue im seeing 2. see point 3. in my op

Comment: Note: built in redis store is coming soon to rails (5.2), so you may get away without the redis-rails gem. See: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/31134