# Is there a canonical pattern for caching something related to a session on the server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session

In my Rails app, once per user session, I need to have my server send a request to one of our other services to get some data about the user. I only want to make this request once per session because pinging another service every time the user makes a request will significantly slow down our response time. However, I can't store this information in a cookie client-side. This information has some security implications - if the user has the ability to lie to our server about what this piece of information is, they can gain access to data they're not authorized to see.

So what is the best way to cache or store a piece of data associated with a session on the Rails server?

I'm considering using [Rails low-level caching](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#low-level-caching), and I think it might even be correct:

```rb
Rails.cache.fetch(session.id, expires_in: 12.hours) do
  OtherServiceAPI.get_sensitive_data(user.id)
end
```

I know that Rails often has one canonical way of doing things, though, so I want to be sure there's not a built-in, officially preferred way to associate a piece of data with a session. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48362296/can-i-use-rails-cache-to-store-short-lived-session-data) makes it look like there are potential pitfalls using the approach I'm considering as well, although it looks like those concerns may have been made obsolete in newer versions of Rails.

Is there a canonical pattern for what I'm trying to do? Or is the approach I'm considering idiomatic enough?

Comment: Rails encrypts the session as a client cookie, so there's no risk of tampering. You can store it in the Rails session and be assured it's not vulnerable or exposed to the user. Doing server-side opens up a whole bunch of other problems, like how do you deal in multi-server environments?

Comment: Hmmm... Looking into it, I'm a little wary of [cookie replay attacks](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#replay-attacks-for-cookiestore-sessions). A malicious user could obtain a cookie from another user and use that to steal that user's sensitive information. Encrypted cookies don't let users easily lie to the server, but is this attack that I'm thinking about plausible?

Comment: If someone's stealing cookies from someone else then you have bigger problems. Think about your threat models. Are you protecting against the NSA or about Billy in Accounting who's trying to cheat his time-cards?